# Twilio TwiML XML String instead of url

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, twilio, google-cloud-endpoints

I want to call the twilio voice API without providing the URL.
Normally you would do it like this using python:

```
call = client.calls.create(url="http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml",
            to=request.receiver,
            from_=sender_number)
```

**Instead of providing the URL I want to provide the XML-String. Is that somehow possible?**

Background:
I'm generating the XML via a google cloud endpoints api. The response is in JSON format and a variable contains the XML. I need to parse the JSON to get the XML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you could use the echo Twimlet.
https://www.twilio.com/labs/twimlets/echo

> Echo will just output whatever TwiML is passed into it via the URL. It is useful for building stateless, outbound apps, where arbitrarily complex content of the call is pre-generated and just passed into the REST API to initiate a call.

Example: http://twimlets.com/echo?Twiml=%3CResponse%3E%3CSay%3EHi+there.%3C%2FSay%3E%3C%2FResponse%3E

Comment: And what if I want user to input digits and want to call back it? Is there a way in Echo?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio Evangelist here. I'm afraid you cannot do this, however there are a number of solutions. If your call doesn't require any dynamic XML, you can host it on S3, or a similar service (I use Dropbox public links quite a lot).

If you do need dynamic XML, then we have a [whole bunch of tutorials](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/python) that can help you get setup with a simple web application.

Hope this helps!